# VMWare: MacOS full screen

Tags: osx-lion, vmware-workstation, fullscreen

I use MacOS image ( pre-install vmware image on internet). It works for me.

But, the problem I have met is: my LCD is 1366x768 (wide sreen ratio), but when I start MacOS. Here is how it appear:

VMWare Logo --> Apple logo --> Login page --> Main Screen

All these screen just happen in normal ratio (mean height side == wide side)

I have successfully done a tutorial to change the resolution
(config file Apple.boot.plist)

But, when I restart again, nothing change.

@: I'm not sure, but when restart, first thing I met is VMWare logo, and it's normal ratio. So, maybe problem is from VMWare ?

Please help me.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

Boy its been a long time and no one has answered this. I am sure @hqt might have figured it out by now. But for other you might stumble upon here looking for answers ( as I did and was disappointed.)

In order to get the desired screen resolution for your guest OSX installation. You can use :

[VM SVGA2](http://sourceforge.net/projects/vmsvga2/files/) from Sourceforge. (**Tip for OSX noob** - Its 3rd party software so OSX wont allow you to open it directly. Simple solution - CTRL + Left click -> Open Or A permanent fix - tinker in System Preference -> Security & Privacy)

Which after installing will give you other options in System Preference -> Display -> Resolutions.

[image: After install - Options]

This I think workd only for VMware virtualization. I tried doing the manual way of changing the "com.apple.Boot.plist" file, But I didnt get it working. I am not sure whether this will work **VirtualBox** virtualization but there are other methods available for it. Check the link provided below.

SOURCE - [LINK](http://www.sysprobs.com/increase-screen-resolution-wide-screen-support-mac-os-virtual-machine-vmware-player-workstation)